# initiate of replica set make unavailable db for long time - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

I have the big database with 35m documents and 11GB size. I want to create replica set for it. so i should `rs.initiate()`, first. As you know since set --replset to `rs.initiate()` completion, mongod have't primary and **isn't available** .
This process **take long time** (7 min). and it very much for us.

while initiating, it raised `oplog.rs` size to 93gb. but didn't remove after initiation completed!!!!!.

How can i initiate without clone file to `oplog.rs` ?? and why oplog size didn't remove after sync ????

Comment: What it's doing during this time is allocating the oplog (in the local database).  Sounds like your disks are quite slow.  Why would you expect it to remove the oplog - it needs it to function as a replica set.  You can specify different size for oplog than the default though - see oplogSize option to mongod.  However, oplog is how secondaries catch up if they are offline for some period of time, so careful you don't make it too small.

Comment: We have hp g8 server with 2TB hard raid-10. I know its possible to change oplog size. but my second question is: after replicate all data to secondary, Do mongodb remove old data of oplog.rs?

Comment: No, oplog is a capped collection, meaning it's like a circular buffer. Its size is fixed once it's pre-allocated.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/